# Conditionally defer expensive calls without factories

Tags: c#

This is more of a theoretical question. Assume I have the following code

```
object ExpensiveOperation()
{
    // some expensive computation
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
void DoIf(bool condition, object expensiveValue)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        // do something with expensiveValue
    }
}

void Foo()
{
    bool maybe = new Random().Next() % 2 == 0;
    DoIf(maybe, ExpensiveOperation());
}
```

Is it possible to defer the method call to `ExpensiveOperation()` to inside the `if` block?

The following options are ruled out:

- Using a factory like `DoIf(bool condition, Func<object> expensiveValueFactory)`.
- Manually inlining `DoIf` (moving the `if` statement into `Foo()`).

In the end I want the test for `condition` to happen before the call to `ExpensiveOperation()`. It's fine if this happens only on asm level after jitting (with optimizations). It doesn't need to be reliable, I'm just curious if it's possible at all. I couldn't come up with anything else than a factory.

Again, this is an artificial sample and more theory crafting than anything else.

Comment: what speaks against the delegate-option mentioned in the (deleted) answer from Jonatahan Barclya? That´s exactly what delegates are made for. How should we give you a "better" solution if we don´t understand what´s whrong with that one?

Comment: @HimBromBeere nothing, as I said it's an artificial example.

Comment: well, dependning on what `ExpansiveOperation` does, you may use `Lazy<T>` to defer the creation of the result-object until it´s needed. However that assumes the expensive things within that operation are just the creation of the result.

Comment: Isn't Lazy also just a factory?

Comment: again: how should we give you a better solution if you don´t provide what problems you have with the correct appraoch?

Comment: I don't want another `call` instruction. If the wrapping in factory gets inlined I guess I'm ok with that as well.

Comment: And yes, `ExpensiveOperation()` has no side effects.

Comment: Why do you not want another method call? Method calls are cheap, by definition your expensive operation is expensive, so the overhead of a simple method call probably irrelevant.

Comment: @JonasH very true. I can only repeat what I've said in the question. I want to know if it is even possible. This isn't and won't be production code, this is pure curiosity.

Comment: It's like you're working at two different levels of abstraction for the same concept but not seeing that they *are* the same concept. Anything that defers the function call *is* a factory.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes those are two different levels of abstractions. But at the asm/IL level there is nothing like defer or a factory. On the higher level abstraction I want to write something that is not a factory. On the lower level abstraction it becomes (semantically) a *factory* by reordering a few instructions. This reordering can also be the result of a compiler optimization (be it csc or jitter).

Comment: You cannot have deferred construction without some kind of method call to defer to. If this method is taken as a parameter it is a kind of factory method, so your question makes little sense. Its like saying you want to call a function without any functions. The compiler might, or might not create a proxy object to provide a level of indirection, but that is an implementation detail.

Comment: @JonasH the compiler could inline `DoIf` and move the argument evaluation (the call to `ExpensiveOperation()`) just before its first use, which is inside the `if` block. There is no need for a proxy object. Yes this is an implementation detail and that is what I'm interested in.

Comment: If you use a `Func<object>` delegate the compiler would be free to optimize this however it wants as long as in maintains behavior, including inlining `DoIf` and `ExpensiveOperation` directly into `Foo`. The more interesting question is if it would actually do this? My guess is no, since this is a very specific case, and the performance improvement will probably be small. But I doubt you will get an authoritative answer for such a question on SO.